# Can I return EXIT_(FAILURE|SUCCESS) from a function?

Tags: c, function

Say I defined a function returns an `int` for a successful flag,

```c
// returns an int representing a successfulness
int not_main_add_element_at_index_of_the_list(list *l, size_t i, void *d) {
    // fail when i > l.size
    // fail when failed to allocate a node
    // ...
    // anyway two possible values for the result: success, failure
}
```

When I intent there should be only two kinds of results, a success and a failure whatever the reason,
Can I return `EXIT_FAILURE` or `EXIT_SUCCESS`?

Or should I stick to the `bool`?

Comment: `bool` is the best option IMO.

Comment: I guess the names are more descriptive than `true` and `false` which are meaningless unless the function name provides a clue what they mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* but you shouldn't. These are reserved for exit codes of the program and should only be used with `exit` family of functions or during `return` from main.

Professional APIs don't usually return `bool` for error handling either, since that's very blunt and doesn't give any info except ok or failure. (As we know from SO, "it isn't working" is a very bad error description.)

The general good practice when it comes to proper API design, is to return a custom typedef:ed `enum` with error codes specific to your module/library. In your case I'd expect to see something like:

```
list_err_t add_item (/* ... */);
```

Comment: or set `errno` if appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

This is a subjective question. By including `stdlib.h`, there is nothing preventing you to use `EXIT_FAILURE` or `EXIT_SUCCESS`.

You could do that.

As you mentioned, you could also use `bool`. I would suggest going this way, because it make the `if` expressions more easy to write `if (element_at_index_of_the_list(..))`. You will find this in open-source code on `GitHub`.

Answer (score 2):

Returning `EXIT_FAILURE` or `EXIT_SUCCESS` from a function that's not `main` is not  idiomatic. It's possible, but I would definitely avoid it. Partly because that whenever you see one of those in code, you'll expect it to exit the program.

But also because if you only have two different return values, then you typically want to use a return value that can be evaluated as true to mean success, but the two exit macros are flipped. `EXIT_SUCCESS` is defined to be zero. Sure, there are library functions that returns zero on success, but personally I prefer that `if(foo())` should run the if block if `foo` succeeded.

In your situation I would not use a `bool` either. I would return a pointer to the added element and `NULL` on failure.

In general, I would only use `bool` as a return type for functions where it would make sense to start their name with `is`. Like `isdigit()` for instance.

I also tend to think about what the most useful return value would be. By returning a pointer to the added element, you're getting BOTH that pointer AND a way of checking for failure. So why choose a `bool` instead?

Same reasoning could be used if you want to write a function to check if a string contains a character. You could either return true if it contains the character, but you could make the function more useful by returning the number of occurrences instead. Unless you need to optimize the code of course.

Comment: *Returning EXIT_FAILURE or EXIT_SUCCESS from a function that's not main is not idiomatic.* However, probably something like half of [the POSIX standard functions listed here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/functions.html) return zero on success and non-zero on failure, so returning zero on success is certainly idiomatic.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Hmmm, you're right, but isn't that because of how `bash` works?

Comment: Or does `bash` work that way because that's how POSIX functions work?  Answering that would probably require some archeological digging into early C and UNIX.

Comment: @AndrewHenle True. However, I'm not claiming that it's non idiomatic to return zero on success. Do you think I need to rephrase to avoid confusion?

Comment: POSIX has 8-bit exit codes, all of which except 0 are interpreted as a failure by the command shell.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do with the result. I would recommend using `bool` from *stdbool.h* because it's a common pattern to test the success or failure of a  function this way, e.g.

```
if (my_function()) {
        //it worked
}
```

But if for some reason you need to test for specific error codes, such as `EXIT_SUCCESS` you could use it, it's just a macro in *stdlib.h*. In this specific case  it doesn't make much sense to do that, since these two codes could be represented by `true` or `false` instead, and they're really [intended for use with the `exit()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/exit-success-exit-failure). It would therefore be better to define your own error codes if you want to indicate specific results in the return value.

Also note that `EXIT_SUCCESS` corresponds to 0 (i.e. `false`) which is what you'd expect in bash when a command did not return an error.